# See all files in S3 bucket using Redshift Spectrum

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

We have S3 buckets which are nested folder structure like `TeamName/Year/Month/Day/<Parquet files 1 - n>`.

We are trying to create a Redshift spectrum (using Glue data catalog) on the S3 folder and query data in Redshift. With all the tutorials I have seen so far, it works with the file directly under the root folder. So how do we see multiple files in redshift that are in the bucket with nested folders?

Also, if we add more files or folder e.g. `Day2/ParquetFiles`, will Spectrum be able to detect this? Is there a way to create spectrum on the root folder? The schema of all files will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just read *any* files in the given path, *including* subdirectories.

Yes, you can add additional files anywhere in that path and they should be included.

From [Creating external tables for Redshift Spectrum - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html):

> The external table statement defines the table columns, the format of your data files, and the location of your data in Amazon S3. Redshift Spectrum **scans the files in the specified folder and any subfolders.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This makes things clearer. I believe to reduce the amount of data scanned in Redshift query, I need to transform/aggregate the data in S3 buckets by date and partition it and use that date in redshift queries.

Comment: If you wish to improve the performance of queries, this is a good thing to do. However, please note that there is a particular naming convention required for partitioned directories and you need to tell Redshift that the data is partitioned. See: [Partitioning Redshift Spectrum external tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html#c-spectrum-external-tables-partitioning).

Comment: I am using Unload command to create S3 files with partition. I am using createdate for partitionining and in S3 folders are of structure weekly/createdate=2022-11-09/... However, when I'm creating external table in Redshift where I give partitioned by createdate clause, I do not see any data. But If I ommit partitioned by I see data using select query. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Perhaps this will assist: [Amazon Redshift Spectrum with partitioned by does not return results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68991135/174777)

Comment: I missed specifying the partition in REdshift by saying alter table partition by. Thanks for your response. One more thing, I am unable to to unload data into previously unloaded folder. I get exception HIVE_PATH_ALREADY_EXISTS: Target directory already exists: Are there any recommendations on how to overcome that?

Comment: It sounds like Redshift doesn't like unloading to an existing folder. You should either delete that folder, or unload to a different location.