# why redshift spectrum does not returning any result after adding partition keys through glue schema?

Tags: partitioning, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have created a glue schema with some tables which contains partition keys and after that i have created a external schema from redshift to form a connection, but while doing a query to that table it executed but did not return anything as result, on other hand if I remove those partition keys from glue table schema then same query is returning a result.

it should return result with or without having partition keys in table schema

Comment: Also referred this link which say use Alter method and add partitions tried that still its not returning anything :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971820/amazon-redshift-spectrum-with-partitioned-by-does-not-return-results